# How to Ignore compile-time errors caused by the "never" type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

[Demonstration of error in TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20PermanentError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toString()%20%20%7B%20return%20%27PermanentError%27%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20example(error%3A%20Error)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(error%20instanceof%20PermanentError)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%27Permanent%20Error%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(error.message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Typescript knows that every call I'm making to this function is passing type `PermanentError`, so inside the else clause the type of the argument "error" has been changed to "never", which causes a compile-time error because never doesn't have a message field:

```
function(error: Error) {
    if (error instanceof PermanentError) {
        // Do stuff

    } else {
        Log(error.message);
    }
}
```

Typescript is correct about the code *now*, but I'd like it handle all possible Errors that future code may pass, what is a good Typescript-2 approach to this problem?

The following didn't work:

```
if (typeof(error) != 'never') Log(error.message);
```

But that is also trying to hack around the flow type analysis, someone more familiar with flow type analysis languages might have an entirely different approach to what I'm doing.

#### Update

Playing with Sohnee's Playground example, it has become clear that the TypeScript error depends on PermanentError, and not what arguments the program passes to the function.

The error [can be seen](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20PermanentError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toString()%20%20%7B%20return%20%27PermanentError%27%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20example(error%3A%20Error)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(error%20instanceof%20PermanentError)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%27Permanent%20Error%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(error.message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) if PermanentError contains toString(), like this:

```
class PermanentError extends Error {
    toString()  { return 'A permanent error'; }
}
```

Oddly however, the addition of another method to that class [makes the error dissappear](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20PermanentError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toString()%20%7B%20return%20%27A%20permanent%20error%27%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20moreMagic()%20%7B%20return%20%27This%20is%20a%20mock%20method%27%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20example(error%3A%20Error)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(error%20instanceof%20PermanentError)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%27Permanent%20Error%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(error.message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D):

```
class PermanentError extends Error {
    toString()  { return 'A permanent error'; }
    moreMagic() { return 'This is a mock method'; }
}
```

As does having [an empty PermanentError class](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20PermanentError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20example(error%3A%20Error)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(error%20instanceof%20PermanentError)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%27Permanent%20Error%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(error.message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D):

```
class PermanentError extends Error {
}
```

Perhaps this is a TypeScript bug and I should take it to their bug tracker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript uses [duck typing](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html). It means that it will compare the class structure, not its name.

In your example, `PermanentError` has the same structure as `Error`, so they are the same. When you check for the `error instanceof PermanentError` it will always be true.

When you change the structure of your `PermanentError`, then it is no longer the same as `Error` and the compiler error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I can only reproduce your situation if I "forget" to extend the `Error` class...

In the below example, the type guard correctly types `error` as `PermanentError` in the `if` and `Error` in the `else`:

```
class PermanentError extends Error {
}

function example(error: Error) {
    if (error instanceof PermanentError) {
        alert('Permanent Error ' + error.name);
    } else {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

I also see no problem when using a structurally sound `PermanentError` that doesn't extend `Error`:

```
class PermanentError {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack: string;
}
```

See this working on the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20PermanentError%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20message%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20stack%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20example(error%3A%20Error)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(error%20instanceof%20PermanentError)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%27Permanent%20Error%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(error.message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20example(new%20Error())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20example(new%20PermanentError())%3B).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "forgetting" to extend the Error class reproduces the issue, but your TypeScript Playground example can be made to reproduce the error if PermanentError extends error AND contains a toString() method - odd. Even stranger... the addition of a second testMethod() to PermanentError removes the TypeScript error - I'll update the main question.

Comment: @Treer - I believe there is something in the type comparison that causes the incorrect identification that the `else` is never reachable, when in fact it is easily reachable.

Comment: Looks like this could be [issue #11664](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11664#issuecomment-254042101), which "hasn't been solved yet and is on the roadmap for future investigation at an unspecified time". Though I don't know why the moreMagic() function is "fixing" it for me.